# How do I skip the jQuery mobile page rendering stage?

Tags: jquery, iphone, android, mobile

I have a large page with lots of form objects that takes ages to render with jQuery mobile.  At any one time most of the elements will be hidden with display:none.

I do not want jQuery mobile to render this page- it takes too long and the native form components are acceptable. I haven't found a way to use `$.mobile.changePage()` and skip the rendering.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

There is **no option** to disable the rendering, unless you make that page an **external link** and load that page normally without using `jquerymobile.js`

What you can also do if part that form, as you say, you don't use most of the fields, why not asking a question to the user first and **show a form with fewer input's**? or automatically show the smallest form input and append a button to "advanced form" where you load the inputs you need... jQMobile way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I might create a div that contains the entire survey, then use jQuery's clone method to load parts of it (and render them) into the page. Sound plausible?

Comment: No!... really, why not go as one form and load (using `.append()`) if user needs more stuff?

Comment: Any part of the form may be required in any order- there is a section index, which allows you to navigate to section four before starting question one.  When the submit button is pressed, the entire survey needs to be validated.  The validation rules are pretty complex, and cover individual questions, groups of questions and sections (groups of groups)

Comment: I've found the answer- I'm now calling $('#survey').page() before inserting the survey content into the page. This stops it rendering- problem solved ;)